# Extracting MySQL data within "tags" using regular expressions?

Tags: mysql, regex, pattern-matching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simulating regex capture groups in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617996/simulating-regex-capture-groups-in-mysql)

Good day,

I have many rows of data stored in a MySQL table. A typical value could look something like this:

```
::image-gallery::
::gallery-entry::images/01.jpg::/gallery-entry::
::/image-gallery::
```

Is there a way - by means of a regular expression that I can a) extract the term image gallery from the first line (it could be any phrase, not just image-gallery) and then extract the center line as two **separate** values like this:

**gallery-entry and then images/01.jpg**

There could be many lines of ::gallery-entry:: values, and they could be called anything as well. A more complete example would be:

```
::image-gallery::
::title::MY GALLERY::/title::
::date::2011-05-20::/date::
::gallery-entry::images/01.jpg::/gallery-entry::
::/image-gallery::
```

In essence I want this information: The content type (image-gallery) in the above case, first line and last line. Then I need the title as a key value style pair, so **title** as the key and *MY GALLERY* as the value. Then, subsequently, I would need all the rows of fields thereafter (gallery-entry) as key value pairs too.

This is for a migration script where data from an old system will be migrated over to a new system with different syntax.

If MySQL select statements would not work, would it be easier to parse the results with a PHP script for data extraction?

Any and all help is always appreciated.

Kind regards,
Simon

Comment: These examples represent a single row in the table?  I would guess that a sql-only solution would be hard to pull off.  From looking quickly at regex support in MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp), I think php or whatever other language you prefer would be an easier way to go.

Comment: hello, you probably need to be more specific about the possible structure of your  data: do the tags enclosing multiple resultset lines ('image-gallery') on their own ?

Comment: @paul W - Sorry for such a delayed response. But indeed I ended up going with PHP's preg_match() function with some simple pattern matching. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
::image-gallery::\s+::title::(.*?)::/title::.*?::gallery-entry::(.*?)::/gallery-entry::\s+::/image-gallery::
```

1. Use single-line mode (/pattern/s) so the .*? chews up newlines.
2. Your key-value pairs will be:
   title: $1 (matching group 1)
   gallery-entry: $2 (matching group 2)

Answer (score 0):

From [simulating-regex-capture-groups-in-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617996/simulating-regex-capture-groups-in-mysql/6625786#6625786) there does not seem to be a way to easily capture groups with a regex in mysql. The reason is that MySQL does not natively support capture groups in a regex. If you want that functionality you can use a server side extension like [lib_mysqludf_preg](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/) to add that capability to MySQL.

The easiest way is to extract the whole column with SQL and then do the text matching in another language (such as php).

In my tests [kenbritton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/470461/kenbritton)'s regex didn't work, but building off of it the following regex worked on your test data:

```
::image-gallery::\s+::title::(.*?)::\/title::\s+(?:.*\s+)*::gallery-entry::(.*?)::\/gallery-entry::\s+::\/image-gallery::
```