# mysql unserialize data

Tags: mysql, wordpress, serialization

Is it possible to unserialize data in the mysql query at the run time? i don't want to use unserialize() function of php.

I need to fetch the value "mathematics" from the below serialized value saved in wp_postmeta table using mysql query.

```
a:4:{s:39:"wpcf-fields-checkboxes-option-223412915";s:7:"science";s:39:"wpcf-fields-checkboxes-option-499894518";s:10:"technology";s:40:"wpcf-fields-checkboxes-option-1474335177";s:11:"engineering";s:40:"wpcf-fields-checkboxes-option-1018405300";s:11:"mathematics";}
```

Comment: You mean you are looking for the `s:11` value just after the `s:40` value = `"wpcf-fields-checkboxes-option-1018405300"`?

Comment: It's gonna get ugly though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617996/simulating-regex-capture-groups-in-mysql

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Actually I wanted to filter my result depending upon the filter value like mathematics, science etc. Eventually i am getting all posts with their related categories (from the wp_postmeta table) and after fetching filtered value like "mathematics" in this example from the query string  i want to filter the entire posts. So i need to put LIKE '%mathematics%' in the meta_value filed for that post. But since using LIKE operator is not recommended so that's why i wanted to know if this is  possible to unserialize the data in the MySQL at the run time.